# Getting data in a specific time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a attendance table name Attendance, may problem is how to get the student_no where the time is equal to morning (0:00 -> 11:59PM) or in the Afternoon is equal to (12:00 -> 11:59PM)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attendance` (
`ATTENDANCE_NO` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`A_DATE` date NOT NULL,
`TIME` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`JOB_SERVICE` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`ATTENDER_NO` int(10) NOT NULL,
`STUDENT_NO` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`ATTENDANCELAT` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`ATTENDANCELONG` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ATTENDANCE_NO`),
KEY `STUDENT_NO` (`STUDENT_NO`),
KEY `ATTENDER_NO` (`ATTENDER_NO`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `attendance`
--

INSERT INTO `attendance` (`ATTENDANCE_NO`, `A_DATE`, `TIME`, `JOB_SERVICE`,       `ATTENDER_NO`, `STUDENT_NO`, `ATTENDANCELAT`, `ATTENDANCELONG`) VALUES
(2, '2014-07-24', '2014-07-24 01:00:00', 'PICKUP', 3, 'S123456789', '13.624004',   '123.194269'),
(3, '2014-07-24', '2014-07-23 18:25:13', 'DROPOFF', 3, 'S123456789', '13.6295657',  '123.184346'),
(4, '2014-07-24', '2014-07-23 17:28:09', 'PICKUP', 3, 'S234567890', '13.625985', '123.191780'),
(5, '2014-07-24', '2014-07-23 18:27:28', 'DROPOFF', 3, 'S234567890', '13.6295657', '123.184346');
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should give sqlFiddle link like this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a41da

Comment: sure, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a41da/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. I hope this will help you.

```
select * from attendance;

#morning time
select * from attendance where 
HOUR(`TIME`) < 12;

#after noon time

select * from attendance where 
HOUR(`TIME`) >= 12;
```

SQLFiddle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a41da/7

also refer all mysql functions for dates : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html